# Can't set error message in Code Igniter 3 when using callback function

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am writing a method that uses `POST` variables posted by `AJAX` to add a user to a certain course in the database, but I can't get the callback to work correctly:

```
 public function enroll()
{
    $package = array();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('course', 'Vak', 'required|callback_not_enrolled');
    $fields = array("course");

    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) === FALSE) {
        $errors = array();
        $success = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $error = form_error($field);
            if ($error !== "") {
                $errors[$field] = $error;
            } else {
                $success[$field] = True;
            }
        }
        $package["field_errors"] = $errors;
        $package["field_success"] = $success;
        $package["success"] = False;
    } else {
        $package["database"] = $this->course_model->enroll_user($this->data["user"], $this->input->post("course"));
        $package["success"] = True;
    }
    echo json_encode($package);
}
```

I wrote the callback `not_enrolled` to check if the user is not already enrolled to the database. Note that I can't use `is_unique` because I have to test the combined uniqueness of two fields (so just one or two separate ones don't do the trick) and the `id` of the user is not included in the form (because it's part of the Code Igniter session).

The callback function:

```
    public function _not_enrolled($course)
    {
    $exists = ($this->user->is_enrolled($course, $this->data["user_id"]) != False);
    if ($exists != False) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message("not_enrolled", "Already enrolled");
        return False;
    } else {
        return True;
    }
}
```

And finally the method `is_enrolled` from the model:

```
    public function is_enrolled($course, $user=False) {
    if($user==False){
        $user = $this->data["user_id"];
    }
    $this->db->select()->from("course_participant")->where("user_id", $user)->where("course_id", $course);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return($query->num_rows()>0);
}
```

Through a call to `var_dump($this->_not_enrolled($existing_course_id));` I know that both the callback function and the method from the model work, as it correctly returned `true`. 
When I `var_dump` the `$package` array or `validation_errors()` I don't get any validation errors except that it says *Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Vak(not_enrolled).*

1. I tried removing the initial *_* from the function name but that gives me a Server Status 500 error.
2. I have another setup *exactly* like this, albeit other database calls, with a callback using the same syntax. This method works perfectly.

Comment: Remove argument `$this` from `$this->form_validation->run($this) === FALSE`.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. Actually added that because it was a suggestion from a different post.

Comment: Then, follow the documentation, remove underscore prepended name of [callback](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods) function. Yes, I saw what you wrote, but it is not CI mistake, but somewhere else in code than.

Comment: Are these all contained within the same class? If so, you don't need $this->user->is_enrolled, you just need $this->is_enrolled